# Change part of the text of a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the deep, distant past of Macintosh programming, you could put "^0" in your dialogs and the UI would replace it with text you had assigned to the 0th string replacement. (This is so long ago, that I don't even remember the terms for this.) I think you could go up to ^3 with the replacements.

Is there anything similar in an iOS `UILabel`?

I have a `UILabel` that is going to display something like: *"You are using ^0 bytes of data."* I would like to replace the ^0 with something programatically. I would prefer to visually design the text in the storyboard and then have the view controller replace just the small part with the accurate value. It would probably make localization easier.

The workaround that I am planning to use, is to not get fancy and just assign the whole `UILabel` text with the complete string. I would prefer to do as much of the visualization of the UI in the storyboard instead of the code. But do current design principles promote that?

Comment: hey friend plz check this link it may solve your problem https://github.com/Abizern/ADNOrdinalNumberFormatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to string with format, like so:

```
labelName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"You are using %f bytes of data.", bytes];
```

**Storyboards** only allow you to set static text and cant dynamicly access objects to change text. This is because your *View* ***cant*** access your model but your model can acces the view. That goes against the MVC paradigm.

Comment: This matches the workaround I was planning on using. It is nice to know that it can't be done. I will be using the suggestions of @matt and using localizable strings.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` at runtime to replace the `^0` part of the text of the label with the text you want.

And by using autolayout, your layout will adjust to accommodate the resizing of your labels.

EDIT: In a comment, you added that you wanted to be able to perform this replacement repeatedly over the life of the app. You can do that by using attributed text and marking the place where the replacement is to go. Here's an example I tested on my own machine, where I replace the middle of the label's text with today's date/time:

```
- (IBAction)doUpdateLabel:(id)sender {
    NSMutableAttributedString* mas = [self.lab.attributedText mutableCopy];
    NSRange r = [mas.string rangeOfString:@"^0"];
    if (r.length) { // first time only
        [mas addAttribute:@"HERE" value:@1 range:r];
        [mas replaceCharactersInRange:r withString:[[NSDate date] description]];
    } else {
        [mas enumerateAttribute:@"HERE" inRange:NSMakeRange(0, mas.length) options:0 
         usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([value isEqual: @1]) {
                [mas replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:[[NSDate date] description]];
                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];
    }
    self.lab.attributedText = mas;
}
```

Comment: There is in fact a considerably more sophisticated way to do this sort of thing when localization is involved. You should watch the WWDC 2013 video on this topic.

Comment: The problem I see with this method is that I can only use it once. After I have replaced the ^0, it is gone and I can't do it again if the values have changed. Otherwise I would be better off using the other suggestions here that all match the workaround I was planning to use already. However, the "Making Your App World-Ready" video was useful and I will use what I learned there when I implement.

Comment: You did not pose this issue in your original question, however: you didn't say that you wanted to be able to substitute text again and again. However, there _is_ a way to do this. Instead of a string, use an attributed string. When you perform the substitution for the first time, mark the stretch of text that you want to replace by a subtle difference in color: just a couple of points in one color component. Now you can forever search on that color and substitute new text for that stretch.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to do the trick with the color! You are allowed to add a custom "marker" attribute. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you would do:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are using %f bytes of data.", myBytesInFloatValue];
```

Here is a handy guide to what kinds of formatting (the %f above) you should use for different types of variables :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1